# How to calculate confidence level for a given sample size and population size?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, sampling, sample-size, proportion

It's been a while since I had statistics in uni, and so I'm a little rusty. I need some help with a fairly straight forward calculation of the confidence level of a sample size. I've been trying to look for an answer on CrossValidated but came to the conclusion that answers are often to complicated for me to quickly grasp. I hope that one of you is kind enough to talk me through an example and provide a formula I can apply in a confidence interval calculator I'm building.

An example: I have a sample size of 1406 respondents ($n$), a population size of 29,245,6752 ($N$), I want to have a confidence level of 95% ($z$ = 1.96) and the percentage of respondents picking a certain option 50% ($p$ = 0.5).

Is there anyone who wants to walk me through the calculation with the data I just gave, and give me the formula so that I can create my calculator? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When constructing confidence intervals usually the size of a population is far larger than the sample size. In these cases we treat the sample as if it came from an infinite population and this simplifies the analysis a bit. For these cases the confidence interval formula is the following

Lower limit:

$$p-z\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}$$

For your example this is $0.5-1.96\sqrt{\frac{0.5(1-0.5)}{1406}}=0.4739$

Upper limit:

$$p+z\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}$$

For your example this is $0.5261$ so the 95% confidence interval for the population value of $p$ is $(0.4739,0.5261)$

**Small population size**

When the size of the population is small then you can make an adjustment to account for this fact. In this case the confidence interval is

Lower limit:

$$p-z\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}\left(\frac{N-n}{N-1} \right)}$$

Upper limit:

$$p+z\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}\left(\frac{N-n}{N-1} \right)}$$

The part under the square root is modified slightly. In your example the population is huge so it's being modified by a factor of $\frac{292456752-1406}{292456752-1}= 0.999995$. You can try calculating the modified confidence interval, it doesn't change the first four decimal places.

**Small sample sizes**

When you sample very few people then the methods used to derive the above formulas can be invalid. A common rule for deciding if sample size is large enough is the following:

If $np > 5$ and $n(1-p)>5$ then the sample size is large enough. Your example certainly has a large enough sample size. When the sample size is too small then you should use a different interval such as the Wilson Score interval:

$$\text{Lower limit} = \frac { 2n\hat{p} + z^2 - \left[z \sqrt{z^2 - \frac{1}{n} + 4n\hat{p}(1 - \hat{p}) + (4\hat{p} - 2)} + 1\right] }
           { 2(n + z^2) }$$

$$\text{Upper limit} = \frac { 2n\hat{p} + z^2 + \left[z \sqrt{z^2 - \frac{1}{n} + 4n\hat{p}(1 - \hat{p}) + (4\hat{p} - 2)} + 1\right] }
           { 2(n + z^2) }$$

If these formulas give a value below $0$ or above $1$ (which is an impossible value for $p$) then round them to $0$ or $1$

This one doesn't have a nice way of adjusting for a small population size. If you have both a small population size and a small sample size I'd recommend prioritizing the small population size and using the second set of confidence interval formulas I described.

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you very much! Would you strictly use the second formula only when you have a small population size? Or can you also use it if you have a large population size?

Comment: @RF_PY You can use it for large population sizes too. I suppose that it's more simple for you to code a calculator to always use the second formula or the third method if the sample size is small

Comment: And what about sample distribution? Do you need a normal sample distribution if you want to calculate the confidence interval?

Comment: All these formulas are for a binomial distribution where you are making a confidence interval for a proportion $p$. A normal distribution has similar formulas but other distributions have more complicated ways to get the confidence interval. What other distributions did you want to include in your calculator?

Comment: So just to give you some more background. I'm calculating confidence intervals for a very extensive survey held in multiple countries. There are a few 100 questions in the survey, and I know that for example the age question is skewed. That being said, I'm currently not looking to find a confidence interval for every single question. I'm hoping to deliver some sort of a general metric about the sample from every country in which we held this survey that gives an indication of the accuracy of our sample.

Comment: @RF_PY For any questions with categories that people can choose from you can calculate $p$ for each category individually. For the occasional question like age where there are no categories you can likely treat it as a normal distribution; although age isn't normally distributed the average age from a random sample is normally distributed because you have a large sample.

Comment: But does the formula as it is now give me a generalizable outcome over the sample distribution of the entire study? Am I right in saying that by using a percentage ($p$) of 50% I'm giving it the worst case percentage, and that I therefore can say that the confidence interval of all question falls at least between a certain confidence interval?

Thanks again for your help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52308/discussion-between-rf-py-and-hugh).

Comment: Also, does a lower limit of 0.4739 means 47% or 0.47%?